# My Array in VBA is returning Empty Values when trying to get data from a range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I have the following VBA code. It is incomplete, but before I can go any further, I would like to understand why my DatesArray nd WorkDayArray show many Empty value, even though there are no empty value in the range I am taking my values from.

```
Public Function ResinOutDate(ByVal Tday As Date, ByVal WDays As Long) As Integer
    Dim DatesArray As Variant
    DatesArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reorder Calculator").Range("A6:A371").Value
    
    Dim WorkDayArray As Variant
    WorkDayArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reorder Calculator").Range("D6:D371").Value
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Workdaycount As Integer
    Workdaycount = 0

    For i = 1 To 366
        If DatesArray(i) = Tday Then
            Do Until Workdaycount = WDays
                Workdaycount = Workdaycount + WorkDayArray(i)
                i = i + 1
            Loop
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    ResinOutDate = i
End Function`
```

[DatesArray Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBNcT.png)

[WorkDayArray Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VbJW.png)

[Source Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50W0t.png)

I have tried searching online if I am doing anything wrong, but all I see are suggestions to use the similar code to the following

```
Dim DatesArray As Variant
    DatesArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reorder Calculator").Range("A6:A371").Value
```

to take a range of value and transform them into an array. Not sure why I am running into this issue.

Comment: I think you will need to provide a reproducible example, or at least share what is actually in those cells. I cannot reproduce this problem - the array is populated perfectly fine, for example, after `Dim days As Variant     days = Sheet1.Range("A1:A365").Value`  ... where A1:A365 are all dates.

Comment: Range A6:A371 is populated with dates with increments of 1, Range D6:D371 contains a sequence of 1s and 0s depending if this is a working day or not. I have attached a photo of the source data in the question above.

Comment: A photo doesn't really cut it. There's nothing wrong with what you've posted so something else is going on with your data.

Comment: You will need to look in the locals window to understand why.  When you get an array from Excel you always get a two dimension array, even when just asking for a row or a column.  So you will either need to use Worksheetfunction.Transpose on your arrays to reduce them to single dimension arrays or use both coordinates when you access by index.

Comment: I don't understand why `If DatesArray(i) = Tday` doesn't error. Shouldn't it be `If DatesArray(i,1) = Tday`?

Comment: Yes, your code should not work at all. It has a syntax error in it. How are you even testing this?

Comment: It is possible that the Watch is not working properly. When I try to display a value from the array, like this ```ResinOutDate = WorkDayArray(i,1)```it shows the actual value and not an empty cell

Comment: I was testing the code by putting a stop before the part where I would get the syntax error and testing to see if my arrays have been created correctly. I did mention that I was not done working on the code and I wanted to solve one issue at a time. Turns out that the Watch did not work properly when referencing data from another sheet (Not sure why). It is working now, and I still appreciate the help on the other issue in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing the code by putting a stop before the part where I would get the syntax error and testing to see if my arrays have been created correctly. Turns out that the Watch did not work properly when referencing data from another sheet (Not sure why). It is working now, and I still appreciate the help on the other issue in the code. There was another error in the code where I needed to either reduce the arrays into a single dimension using transpose or use `DatesArray(i,1)` & `WorkDayArray(i,1)`.